# Fragment not instantiating correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem instantiating Fragments in my program using the Support Library implementation. Here's a brief description of the task I'm attempting to perform and some of my attempts which haven't yet borne fruit:

The UI of my application is subject to change to meet user preferences.  In order to do this, I'm using a Fragment for each different layout and replacing the active Fragment in the UI at a given time as per the user's instructions.  Here are some ways I've tried (and failed) to do this:

- I've tried adding the Fragments as non-static inner classes in my Activity.  This approach worked so long as the user did not rotate the device.  As soon as the user rotated the device, the application crashed (this is true for Portrait -> Landscape rotation and for `Landscape -> Portrait rotation)`.  Upon checking the issue using the emulator, I was getting an **InstantiationException**.  I checked SO for some help, which led me to:
- Implement the Fragment as a static inner class.  When the Fragment initiates, it will expand its layout, and then from later in the control flow of the Activity, I can do stuff to the Fragment's subviews (in particular, add listeners to the buttons).  Unfortunately this didn't work because I couldn't refer to the Fragment's subviews using `[frag_name].getView().findViewById()`.  Something about referencing static objects in a non-static context.  Once again, I checked SO, which led me to:
- Implement the Fragment as a separate class altogether from the Activity.  This seems to be what the Dev docs on developer.android.com recommend.  Upon doing this, everything seems to compile fine, but when I try to refer to the Fragment's subviews (once again, using `[frag_name].getView().findViewById())`, I get a **NullPointerException**.  When I add System.out.println() statements across my code to find out exactly what is happening, I find that the print statement inside onCreateView in the fragment is never getting fired, which implies that onCreateView is never getting triggered.

So now, I'm stuck.  What am I doing wrong?  The precise implementation of this isn't as important as learning something from the experience so I can get better at Android development, so if seperate classes are better than static classes or vice-versa, I don't really care which I use.

Thanks.

Comment: please post code of activity.

Comment: @jeet: The Activity is about 400 lines long, and I'd prefer to keep it off public domain; what part of the code do you need to see, precisely?

Comment: @user1420101: I copied the code from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.  Specifically the ExampleFragment.  I've changed some of the names of the variables, but otherwise the code is a precise copy of that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Turns out that in order to do what I wanted, I had to register the Activity as a Listener to each of the Fragments and pass "ready to enable buttons" messages back and forth between the two.  To anyone using this question for further research, the guide on how to do that is located on the Android Developer guide, here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html